# issue in JSP:forward on button Click()(when target jsp is under web-inf folder)

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets

I have Two Jsp:
**1. index.jsp
2. createAccount.jsp** **(Under WEB-INF folder)**

Index.jsp should show createAccount button.When i click createAccount Button jsp should be forwarded to createAccount.jsp.

**Current Issue:** When I deploy the code on Tomcat While accessing index.jsp It automatically forwards to createAccount.jsp without showing the createAccount button.

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"

pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head><title>Vendor Account</title></head>
  <body>
  <input type="button" value="Create Vendor Account" 
  onclick='<jsp:forward page="WEB-INF/jsp/createAccount.jsp"></jsp:forward>'>


  </body>
</html>
```

**createAccount.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Vendor Account Creation Form</title>
</head>
<body>
This is a Vendor Creation Form.
</body>
</html>
```

Actual Output: http://:8081/VendorPortal/index.jsp
This is a Vendor Creation Form.

Expected output :

Create Vendor Account button should be displayed.

**Please let me know how to Implement the above scenario.**

Answer (score 2):

Forward (no matter, if it is jsp:forward or requestDispatcher.forward() ) executes at the server side, not at the client side, so it needs controller component to call it. It usually is servlet, but can be also jsp. In that jsp you need to detect, when to forward (which is not recommended as it mix controller logic with presentation logic).

And why you cannot access WEB-INF/... directly from the browser? - Because specification forbids it.

***Disclaimer - this is very ugly and not recommended*** but you wanted alternatives.
You can use your index.jsp as controller. Form submits to itself and you detect it and forward to target jsp.

Change your index.jsp like this:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%
if(request.getParameter("submit1") != null) {
%>
<jsp:forward page="WEB-INF/jsp/createAccount.jsp"></jsp:forward>    
<%
  return;
}
%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head><title>Vendor Account</title></head>
  <body>
<form action="index.jsp">
<input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Create Vendor Account">
</form>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

something like:

```
<form action='createAccount.jsp'><input type='submit' value='Create Vendor Account' /></form>
```

or using onclick javascript:

```
<input type="button" value="Create Vendor Account" onClick="javascript:window.location='createAccount.jsp';">
```

use appropriate path to your target jsp

Comment: I have Tried the above Its not working,As The target jsp are under web-inf folder.

Comment: You either need to move that jsp to the root folder (not WEB-INF) or create some kind of controller e.g. servlet that will receive that request and forward to jsp. Files in WEB-INF are not directly accessible. Look for posts about MVC pattern for more details.

Comment: I cant move out of web-inf folder. Is there no alternative way without writing controller servlet.Why it is like that for simple jsp forward we have to write a controller or move out of web-inf folder There should be some alternative way I have posted the Question to look for some other alternative or for an Strong justification why it cant happen without writing the Controller.

Comment: Please take this Question Seriously.It is very basic question but requires Strong Justification.